# R Shiny selectInput Reactivity

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-reactivity

In my Shiny app,  I have a selectInput named bob in my UI with choices "A", "B", "C".

At the top of my server (before anything else) I have

```
observe({

bob_value <- reactive({

      if (input$bob == "A")
      {bob_value <- "A"
      } else if (input$bob == "B")
       {bob_value <- "B"
      } else if (input$bob == "C")
       {bob_value <- "C"}
        bob_value
                      })

        .............................

       })
```

Where the dots indicate around ten million and six lines of code.

Now, the ten million and six lines of code largely mention several big function files, of which one of the arguments is alice. I want to make alice reactive to bob_value, so that I could change input$bob in the UI and see a change in the output of the ten million and six lines of code. So I was planning on setting all the alices to bob_value(), but before I could do that I get the error:

Error in ==: comparison (1) is possible only for atomic and list types

I would appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should use:
   alices<-bob_value()

Comment: Thanks, but this happened before I changed any alices at all. I'm sorry I can't post the reproducible code.

Comment: In your ui, is bob a vector or a list then?

Comment: It's a vector. (It's of the type c("A", "B", "C"). That's a vector, right? )

Comment: Why don't you just use input$bob to put in the functions, it seems that what you are doing is quite redundant. There is not point creating a reactive object here?